# js and rails how to disable button if not select something in collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand what I do wrong. Can you help me?  I want to make the button disabled if user not select anything in the selected field. 
What I have:

```
Button:
  = f.submit t('etc.actions.send'), data: {style: 'expand-left'}, class: 'ladda-button btn btn-success'

Select input field: 
  = f.input :id, collection: [['None', nil]] + @company.lead_sources.order(:name).map{ |ls| [ls.name, ls.id] }, label: 'Assign Lead Source', class: 'abc'
```

## view_file

```
.modal-body
  .row.m-t-md
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12
      = f.input :id, collection: [['None', nil]] + @company.lead_sources.order(:name).map{ |ls| [ls.name, ls.id] }, label: 'Assign Lead Source', class: 'abc'
.modal-footer
  .actions
    .pull-right
      = link_to t('etc.actions.cancel'), '#', class: 'btn btn-default', data: {dismiss: 'modal'}
      = f.submit t('etc.actions.send'), data: {style: 'expand-left'}, class: 'ladda-button btn btn-success'

javascript:
   $('#abc').on('change', function () {
      $('#ladda-button btn btn-success').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
  }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Where is `btn btn-default` and is it id or class as you are using it as id.

Comment: edited example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
javascript:
  $('.abc').on('change', function () {
    $('.ladda-button').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

**Explanation:**

You are doing `$('#abc')` and `$('#ladda-button')`. `#` is used to find the elements by their id. [For classes, you use `.`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). In your HTML, `'abc'`, `'ladder-button'`, `'btn'`, and `'btn-success'` are all classes.

Comment: instead '.ladda button' i added class 'abc" and added this class to the f.input, and works fine. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should make the button disabled by default:

```
$('.ladda-button').prop("disabled", true);
```

And then on change in the select input field, make it active:

```
$('.abc').on('change', function(){

    $('.ladda-button').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

Comment: There are no elements `<btn>` and `<btn-success>` in the HTML. So, `$('.ladda-button btn btn-success')` won't return any elements.